# Github - Proper steps before creating a pull request

Tags: git, github

I have been used to creating local git branches for development. Before pushing my code changes, I would do a pull so that I have the latest changes.

Looks like Github encourages creating a tracking branch instead of just a local branch.

Let's say our main branch is "main." I create my tracking branch as "feature-A." I am the only one who would work on feature-A. Other developers would create their own tracking branches. Once the pull request is approved, the code automatically gets merged into "main."

If I have to push my changes, running "git pull" would not result in pulling any changes. The changes are in the "main" branch, not my "feature-A" branch.

I am now using the following command:

```
 $ git merge main --no-commit
```

Basically, I am merging "main" into my current branch. Now I have the latest changes from main branch as well as my own changes in the local branch. I can now proceed with committing the changes and creating a pull request.

I am wondering if this is the right approach. Looks like "pull before push" adage is becoming "merge before push." Or, is there a better way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: well a pull is effectively a fetch and merge so pull-before-push is also merge-before-push. You sound like you are approaching this right. Just make sure you read any `README.md`  or  `CONTRIBUTING.md` to make sure you follow any project specific practices or steps

Comment: A pretty great way to get upstream changes into your local feature branch is `git pull --rebase --autostash origin main` (if the remote's name is `origin`).